# Read input until a specific string is found C++

Tags: c++, linux, string

I'm currently using this code to take in standard input and place it in a string. then tokenize using the delimeter #

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin,input, '\0');
std::string delimiter = "#";
StringTokenizer strtok(input,delimiter);
```

This makes getline read until null character is found(I think) and pass the entire string into input.This works fine in windows when I run the cmd and write this :

```
myprogram.exe 0 <testme.txt
```

I get the output I am expecting.The problem I am having is when I try to run a similar command in linux terminal(a.out is my program)

```
./a.out < testme.txt
```

It will not stop looking for keyboard input until I push ctrl-z. This is also the case when I run in my IDE Code::blocks where the program is written. Both Code::blocks and linux compile with g++ with no errors or warnings. I think my issue lies with the waiting for a null character. The reason for using the null character is because my input is on multiple lines and when I just used getline(std::cin,input) only the first line was read.

Example testme.txt

```
 A B C D E F #
 A -> Bab #
 B -> C #
 ##
```

Sample of what I'm doing with my code

```
std::string data;
std::getline(std::cin,data, '\0');
std::string delimiter = "#";
StringTokenizer strtok(data,delimiter);
// places first token in tk1
std::string t1      = strtok.nextToken();
std::string tk1(t1);
// places next token in tk2
std::string t2      = strtok.nextToken();
std::string tk2(t2);
if(checkstring(tk2,"a") > 0) // this function checks the amount of "a"s in the token. I only care if there is at least 1 "a" so that is what the if statements are for.
    {
      a = a + 1;
    }
// do this if statement for every letter
// example: token = A -> abbbababababa then will print out a = 1 and b = 1
```

If put through my program the testme.txt should make my program output this:

```
 A B C D E F
 a= 1
 b= 1
```

**MY QUESTION**

Each of my testme.txt files ends with the two characters ##. Is there a way that I can stop reading input when this string(?) is reached instead of waiting for the null character?

Comment: `strtok()` is the worst option to choose.

Comment: add a seond delimiter with different characters than the first one?

Comment: why not pass the filename and just read the file?!

Comment: @deW1 I need to take in standard input so I wont know what the name of the txt is. It has to work for any standard input.

Comment: Can you tell more precisely what you want?

Comment: how can I tell getline() to stop looking for input when ## is reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do{
//do stuff
if (yourString == "##")
    break;
}while(yourString != NULL);
```

Sometimes its easier than it seems

Edit
All your '#' are useless, if you delete them:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens; // Storing all tokens
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line))
    tokens.push_back(line);

for (std::string s : tokens) //Gets all tokens one by one
    for (char c : s)// Gets all char in each token
        if (islower(c))// Checks if thats a lowercase letter
            std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

If you want to keep the '#':

```
while (std::getline(file, line))
    if (!line.find("#"));
        tokens.push_back(line);
```

If you're using std::cin instead of a file:

```
std::string input, line;
std::cin >> input;
std::stringstream sinput(input);

while (std::getline(sinput, line, '#'))
    tokens.push_back(line);
```

Comment: Tell me shortly what your programm exaclty does

Comment: my program reads in a standard input and places it to a string(input) it then tokenizes this string by the delimiter # using strtok. it then calls the function nexttoken() and places the token into a string. it then checks every token after tk1 if that token contains a lowercase letter and outputs ex:( if tk2 contains "a" then it would output a = 1 etc) every input file ends with ##.

Comment: I think the only thing that needs to be changed is the way I am reading in the input. getline(std::string,input,'\0') seems to never stop looking for input because it cannot find \0. Is there a way I can make getline() (or another function) stop looking for input when it sees ##?

Comment: not getline() itself, but you can stop when the string that getline() modifies is equl to "##" as in my first answer, also, getline() returns a null pointer at the end of the file it reads

Comment: so would I write if(std::cin == "##") or would I put input there? also I am getting this error "no match for 'operator !='"

Comment: I changed the delimiter to "\n" because the ## was messing it up. but when I break after checking for ## it doesn't check for lowercase or output anything. how would I structure your example around my code so that It still does everything else?

Comment: Why are you using a delimiter?